# undefined control sequence \abx@aux@sortscheme

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I am trying to start a basic tex document with bibtex citations as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblo}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

However, when I run `pdflatex mytexfile.tex` I receive the error that `\abx@aux@sortscheme` is undefined.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: The syntax should be `\addbibresource{biblo.bib}`.

Comment: I think this error occurs after having changed some options to `biblatex` or removing the inclusion itself, then recompiling --> there is some code left in `.aux` file. Try to remove the aux-file

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, but `\bibliography{biblo}` still works (however not recommended)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: That Biblatex is really a good lad…

Comment: @Bernard: On page 71 of current `biblatex.pdf`: *`\bibliography ... The legacy command...`* and as a marginnote: `Deprecated` (see at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Thank you, Christian, that was the problem.  If you'd like to post that comment as an answer, I'd accept it.  Again, thank you for your help.  (Bernard, I have also made your suggestion.  Thank you as well.)

Comment: Solution: Delete the .aux file and recompile.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The reported error `\abx@aux@sortscheme` being undefined is a consequence of changing options to `biblatex` or having removed the `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}` entry followed by recompilation.

`@aux` indicates that this setting is written to the `.aux` file, after changing or removing this entry is still left in the `.aux` file and causes the error message during the next run.

Solution: Delete the `.aux` file and recompile.

A similar error occurs when changing language options from `babel`.

Side note: `\bibliography` is a deprecated command in conjunction with `biblatex` -- use `\addbibresource` instead.

Comment: How to fix it in Overleaf?
Ans: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache