# Overleaf TeX compiler fails to compile one document, which compiles perfectly in a project copy

Tags: pdftex

Suddendly my Latex file stopped compiling (with over 50 errors - all not helpful like `missing \begin{document}` ), uploading the last version that compiled also fails. What is even more confusing is that I created a new project, copy-pasted the same file, and that compiles without any issues.

What could have gone wrong? Did the compiler somehow get a different configuration?

Error messages:

```
Compile Error. Sorry, your LaTeX code couldn't compile for some reason. 

Please check the errors below for details, or view the raw log.
 output.aux, line 2

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.2 \abx@aux@sortscheme
                       {none}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 2

LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

No \begin{document} command was found. Make sure you have included \begin{document} in your preamble, and that your main document is set correctly.
 Learn more

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2 \abx@aux@sortscheme{n
                         one}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \abx@aux@refcontext
                       {none/global/}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 4

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.4 \abx@aux@cite
                 {konukoglu_monitoring_2008}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.4 \abx@aux@cite{konukoglu_
                            monitoring_2008}
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
 output.aux, line 4

Extra }, or forgotten $.

l.4 \abx@aux@cite{konukoglu_monitoring_2008}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
 output.aux, line 5

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.5 \abx@aux@segm
                 {0}{0}{konukoglu_monitoring_2008}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \abx@aux@cite
                 {bauer_survey_2013}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 7

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.7 \abx@aux@segm
                 {0}{0}{bauer_survey_2013}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \abx@aux@cite
                 {alexander_correlating_2010}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 9

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.9 \abx@aux@segm
                 {0}{0}{alexander_correlating_2010}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \abx@aux@cite
                  {crinion_neuroimaging_2013}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 11

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.11 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{crinion_neuroimaging_2013}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \abx@aux@cite
                  {llado_segmentation_2012}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 13

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.13 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{llado_segmentation_2012}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.14 \abx@aux@cite
                  {pustina_automated_2016}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 15

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.15 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{pustina_automated_2016}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.16 \abx@aux@cite
                  {mckinley_fully_2017}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 17

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.17 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{mckinley_fully_2017}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.18 \abx@aux@cite
                  {seghier_lesion_2008}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 19

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.19 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{seghier_lesion_2008}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.20 \abx@aux@cite
                  {dmochowski_targeted_2013}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 21

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.21 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{dmochowski_targeted_2013}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.22 \abx@aux@cite
                  {dmochowski_optimized_2011}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 23

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.23 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{dmochowski_optimized_2011}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.24 \abx@aux@cite
                  {huang_automated_2013}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 25

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.25 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{huang_automated_2013}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.26 \abx@aux@cite
                  {datta_individualized_2011}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 27

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.27 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{datta_individualized_2011}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.28 \abx@aux@cite
                  {ashburner_unified_2005}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 29

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.29 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{ashburner_unified_2005}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.30 \abx@aux@cite
                  {smith_advances_2004}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 31

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.31 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{smith_advances_2004}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.32 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{ashburner_unified_2005}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 33

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.33 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{pustina_automated_2016}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.34 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{mckinley_fully_2017}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 35

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.35 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{seghier_lesion_2008}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.36 \abx@aux@cite
                  {kamnitsas_efficient_2017}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 37

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.37 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{kamnitsas_efficient_2017}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.38 \abx@aux@cite
                  {guha_roy_quicknat:_2018}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 39

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.39 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{guha_roy_quicknat:_2018}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.40 \abx@aux@cite
                  {ghafoorian_location_2017}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 41

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.41 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{ghafoorian_location_2017}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.42 \abx@aux@cite
                  {wachinger_deepnat:_2018}


==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: if you want help understanding an error message, it helps if you show the message. You could clear the aux files (in the logs menu) or perhaps you have chosen the wrong typesetting engine. Impossible to say, the error message would make that clear.

Comment: But isn't the issue irrelevant to the error messages? My question is how can the same latex document raise errors in one project and none in another?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Error messages are _always_ relevant. It's the computer telling you what's wrong. However Overleaf did update from TL 17 to TL 18, so this might be the cause of the difference. In their blog post they said that new projects would use TL 18, while projects that still existed would still use TL 17.

Comment: its a copy-paste. Same text. If there was something different then the answer would be trivially obvious

Comment: No, there is something different _in the project_ the document text might be identical but being processed differently. If you give no information then no one can help, sorry.

Comment: @user198440 This blog post lists the changes: https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-upgrade-september-2019. But mind you that what David said may also be the issue: You have exact copies of the files, but if you run on a different engine, the output is not certain.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Right, if the engine is different then that is a clear hint. Both running pdflatex though

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Deleted the cache, but errors still persist. That was another good suggestion on differences between the two files. I added the error messages (not complete as they become redundant), they all refer to syntax error which should be the same in the project-copy, but I'm probably wrong

Comment: the actual tex errors from tthe log would be clearer but from the errors shown you can see the error is from biblatex and searching for this site suggests that clearing the aux files should fix it https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328857/undefined-control-sequence-abxauxsortscheme are you sure they were cleared)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle correctly deleting the aux files cleared the compilation errors. If you post this as an answer Ill accept it. This answers perfectly the original question: how can the same latex document raise errors in one project and none in another? cached files!